# Xamarin Android - How to select a video app to open from a URI?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, video-streaming

As if, for example, I would select a video file from a file manager (or provide an URL) and I would like to then get a popup asking me "on which app do you want to play it on?", like VLC Player.

I am not sure how to construct a working intent for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code in Java to ask the user to select a video, then ask the user to choose a program to open it (Converting the syntax to C# it pretty easy, since the APIs are the same):

```
final int VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                               MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        Uri videoUri = data.getData();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(resolver.getType(videoUri));

        intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, type);

        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for..
I searched for java codes too.. but perhaps I searched with wrong keywords as I found nothing